# What is the difference between |U and U regarding numpy dtype specifier for strings

Tags: python, numpy

I know that

`header = np.array(["AA","AC"],dtype='U2')`

will create a numpy array containing strings that are made out of 2 letters.

How does it difer compared to

`header = np.array(["AA","AC"],dtype='|U2')`
?

Comment: Is the `dtype` (after creating the array) any different?